# Laravel: view and controller in same directory

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to have views and controllers under the same directory in Laravel?

I am looking to achieve something like this:

```
.
├── app
|   └── Index
|       ├── Controller.php
|       ├── index.blade.php
|       ├── SomeService.php
|       └── SomeRepository.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`addNamespace()`](https://github.com/illuminate/view/blob/master/Factory.php#L368) to add a new namespace and use your views as you would [use views from some package](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#views):

```
view()->addNamespace('index', base_path('app/Index'));
return view('index::blade.view');
```